# How to turn lists of lists into integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to transform a single list of strings into integers...
But how do I transform lists of lists (strings) from into integers

I want this list:

['[1,', '3]', '[3,', '4]', '[5,', '8]', '[6,', '10]']

become a list of integers:

[1, 3], [3, 4], [5, 8], [6, 10]

Comment: This may need a more complicated parser.

Comment: How did you get this list? There might be an easier way to get to the desired result if we load the data in a different way.

Comment: isn't this a list of list of strings? (not sure your example and description match above). 
listOfListOfstrings = [['1,', '3'], ['3,', '4'], ['5,', '8'], ['6,', '10']]

Comment: did you actually search the site? seems I found a dupe.

Comment: could this question be opened again? It has been closed as a duplicate but the question that is linked is different from the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your example data, is that there's no commas between lists, you could do something like this to parse the different lists:

```
>>> parsed = re.findall(r'\[.+?\]', ''.join(data))
['[1,3]', '[3,4]', '[5,8]', '[6,10]']

>>> ast.literal_eval(', '.join(parsed))
([1, 3], [3, 4], [5, 8], [6, 10])
```